# Not properly converting epoch time to normal time in PHP

Tags: php, epoch

Here is my code which I have used to convert the EPOCH time to normal time in PHP. I haven't set timezone as its not required. In the following code `$timeD` is the input time which is getting properly converted in http://www.epochconverter.com/

```
 $timeD = 1449034934000;
 echo gmdate('r', $timeD);
```

Expected output is this 12/2/2015, 11:12:14 AM GMT+5:30. But what is getting is

> Wed, 08 Feb 47888 14:56:40 +0000

Answer (score 1):

The time you're using has millisecond precision (probably from Javascript) so you simply need to chop the last three digits off the timestamp. **`1449034934`** vs `1449034934000`

```
$timeD = 1449034934000; //$timeD = 1449034934; is what we want.
$timeD = substr($timeD,0,10); // Chop off those pesky unnecessary milliseconds!
echo gmdate('r', $timeD);
```

Comment: thank you loads dude.. you solved my problem. thank you again. i would appreciate you more if you can guide me on next as. how can i add +5.30 Hr in output of your program.

Comment: @yudihukkeri This might work for you: **`echo date('m/d/Y h:i:sA P',$timeD);`** for me I get `12/01/2015 09:42:14PM -08:00` .. I'm in different timezone so let me know if it needs adjusting

Comment: Thank you for comments @nextlocal